# New to Godot and cannot figure out what is the AnimationTree doing :(

Tags: game-development, godot4

[Animation Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/usC0L.png)

[Blend Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZKy3.png)

I cannot figure out why I cannot add to blend tree or what it means by No triangles exist, so no blending can take place. How do I proceed?

I tried to animate my slime based on https://youtu.be/WrMORzl3g1U?t=531 but I can't figure out why I cannot add an animation to the blend tree thingy.